# Jenkinsfile maven plugin inside a docker container

Tags: java, maven, docker, jenkins, artifactory

I'm using Jenkins with a Jenkinsfile that runs my builds inside a docker container. I have a simple Java application that I'd like to build and deploy to artifactory using the Jenkins Artifactory plugin.

My Jenkinsfile is below -

```
node {
  def server = Artifactory.server "my-artifactory"
  def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()

  stage("Prepare environment"){
    docker.image('driv/docker-maven-java-oracle').inside {

      checkout scm

      stage("Artifactory configuration") {
        rtMaven.deployer releaseRepo:'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo:'libs-snapshot-local', server: server
        rtMaven.resolver releaseRepo:'libs-release', snapshotRepo:'libs-snapshot', server: server
      }

      stage("Maven build") {
        def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I run builds with the above Jenkinsfile I get the error -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find maven installation
```

I know that I can add a line to my Jenkinsfile like this -

```
rtMaven.tool = MAVEN_TOOL
```

...that I can use to specify a pre-configured Jenkins Tool to point the Artifactory plugin at Maven. However, it seems to me that such a pre-configured tool would have to be on the Jenkins machine, or a build node, and not inside my docker container.

So, is it possible to point the Artifactory plugin at a maven installation inside my docker container?

Thanks.

Comment: The `MAVEN_HOME` environment variable is set by the container, but the plugin appears to look at the build environment variables on the running node rather than in the container when trying to find a Maven installation. You might be able to map the Maven installation directory on the Jenkins agent into the container — there is some syntax that allows you to pass extra parameters when starting the container.

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea. Thanks, I'll see if I can do it that way.

Comment: @Jez were you able to do that? can you share the script?

Comment: @BennyBauer No. In the end I used a maven plugin to talk to artifactory (configured in the POM), rather than a Jenkins plugin.

Comment: Is this still broken? all modern jenkins pipelines run in containers. inside of an sh step I can see MAVEN_HOME is set correctly

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be fixed in their jenkins plugin itself but as "Christopher Orr" suggested mapping environment vars at the pipeline stage level to the same ones set in the container work

For example

```
stage('mystage') {
    environment {
        // If your using the official maven image, these are probably where it puts it
        MAVEN_HOME = '/usr/share/maven'
        JAVA_HOME= '/usr/local/openjdk-8'
    }
    steps {
        sh """
            # confirm location of MAVEN_HOME and JAVA_HOME in container and set in environment directive
            printenv 
        """
        ...
        // call rtMavenRun()
```